# How to extract text "lower" in a div

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract all locations from a web page that are grouped into a large id=results div.

https://www.dynacast.com/en-gb/discover-dynacast/locations

My current code produces an empty list that I cannot interact with:

```
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser(soup_config={'features': 'lxml'}
locations_page = browser.page
locations_list = locations_page.find_all("div", id="location-list")
for locations_grid in locations_list:
    grid = locations_grid.find_all_next("div", class_="grid-4")
print(grid)
Output = []
```

My aim is to extract all the text from this locations table (North America, Europe etc.) and the locations within the continents and append it to a list. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The page is dynamic so you won't get that html from a simple request. My suggestion is just get the data in json format from the api and can use pandas to normalize it:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.dynacast.com/api/sitecore/Location/LocationsByServiceAjax'
payload = {
'serviceId': '',
'contextItemId': 'a9640857-ede5-47b3-a692-1606ee151d7c'}
jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()

df = pd.json_normalize(jsonData)
```

**Output: 1st 5 of 15 rows below**

```
print(df.head(5).to_string())
                                     Id                              LocationName                                                                                                    LocationAddress                    Phone Continent    Country                                                                                                DirectionsLink CountryUrl                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          Content    Latitude    Longitude                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            SummaryContent SalesPhone                                                  ItemUrl  IsFeatured
0  7ec388a8-adfa-4652-90b7-af1a089dfba1                          Dynacast Tunisia  Parc d'Activités Economiques de Bizerte\r\nSite de Menzel Bourguiba II BP 130\r\n7050 Menzel Bourguiba\r\nTunisie            +216 72418363    Africa    Tunisia  https://www.google.com/maps?daddr=Parc+d%27Activit%C3%A9s+Economiques%2BMenzel+Bourguiba%2BBizerte%2BTunisia                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         <p>Dynacast acquired Taurus Tunisia in 2016; it is located in Menzel Bourguiba, Bizerte, Tunisia just 30 minutes from the Tunis International Airport. This 1,900m<sup>2</sup> facility specializes in precision zinc die casting. Additional details about this location include:</p>\n<ul>\n<li>12 conventional zinc die casting machines ranging from 20T to 135T</li>\n<li>Production range from 0.5g to 0.9 kg</li>\n<li>Assembly operations&nbsp;</li>\n<li>In-house tool maintenance and repair</li>\n<li>Wide range of secondary operations and surface finishes including milling, thread cutting, sand blasting, and tumbling</li>\n</ul>  37.1450007    9.8045612                                                                                    <p>Dynacast acquired Taurus Tunisia in 2016; it is located in Menzel Bourguiba, Bizerte, Tunisia.&nbsp;This 1,900m<sup>2</sup> facility specializes in precision zinc die casting.</p>                    /en/discover-dynacast/locations/dynacast-tunisia       False
1  a7138364-2693-45b7-a886-4d526a325428                   Sundaram Dynacast India                               No. 25 A/2, Sidco Industrial Park\nNorth Phase, Ambattur\nChennai, Tamil Nadu 600098         +91.44.2625.9169      Asia      India        https://www.google.com/maps?daddr=No.+25+A%2F2%2C+Sidco+Industrial+Park%2BChennai%2BTamil+Nadu%2BIndia                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                <p>Sundaram Dynacast is a 68,000 square foot facility located in Ambattur, Chennai, India. The facility is the largest zinc high pressure hot chamber die caster in this area. Below are additional details about what is offered at this location:</p>\n<ul>\n<li>19 multi-slide proprietary zinc die casting machines ranging from 2.5 to 4.5 tons</li>\n<li>7 standard zinc die casting machines ranging from 25 to 63 tons</li>\n<li>8 aluminum die casting machine ranging from 125T to 350 tons</li>\n<li>Precision tool building with in-house capabilities</li>\n<li>Wide range of secondary operations including CNC machining, tapping, reaming, drilling, and assembly available through certified/dedicated partners</li>\n<li>Wide range of surface finishes are available in-house including tumbling, polishing, shot blasting, de-burring etc.. Plating, powder coating etc. are supported through our certified partners</li>\n</ul>\n<p />  13.1094448   80.1666248                                                                                  <p>Sundaram Dynacast is a 68,000 square foot facility located in Ambattur, Chennai, India. The facility is the largest zinc high pressure hot chamber die caster in this area.&nbsp;</p>             /en/discover-dynacast/locations/sundaram-dynacast-india       False
2  a2129999-b0d7-458b-bdd4-ae8a15dd4276                        Dynacast Singapore                                                                           6 Second Chin Bee Road\r\nJurong, 618773    65.6268.7644 ext. 135      Asia  Singapore                                                                                                                                                                                            <p>Dynacast Singapore focuses on multi-slide zinc, conventional zinc, aluminum, and magnesium die casting. Below are additional details about what is offered at the Singapore location:</p>\n<ul>\n<li>40 multi-slide proprietary zinc die casting machines ranging from 4 to 27 tons</li>\n<li>1 standard zinc die casting machines up to 125 tons</li>\n<li>4 aluminum die casting machines up to 135 tons</li>\n<li>1 multi-slide magnesium die casting machine up to 20 tons</li>\n<li>Precision tool building with in-house capabilities</li>\n<li>Wide range of secondary operations including CNC machining, tapping, reaming, and drilling available in house and through certified partners</li>\n<li>Design, prototyping, and modeling services</li>\n<li>Wide range of finishing surfaces available including tumbling, polishing, shot blasting and thermal de-burring</li>\n</ul>\n<p><a href="http://www.dynacast.com.sg" target="_blank">www.dynacast.com.sg</a></p>\n<p><br /><strong>Dynacast Singapore works with <a href="https://www.optimim.com/">OptiMIM</a>, utilizing&nbsp;state-of-the-art metal injection molding technology to create high performing small precision metal components to almost any level of complexity and at virtually any volume.</strong></p>    1.332509   103.714238                                                                                                                                                      <p>Dynacast Singapore focuses on multi-slide zinc, conventional zinc, aluminum, and magnesium die casting.&nbsp;</p>                  /en/discover-dynacast/locations/dynacast-singapore       False
3  f2dd9429-d9d4-4028-b8ca-227972771980  Dynacast Tokyo (Regional Support Office)                                          Azabu Green Terrace 5F\r\nMinamiazabu 3-20-1\r\nMinato-ku, Tokyo 106-0047            +03 6859-8512      Asia      Japan                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          <p>Dynacast&nbsp;Tokyo is a Regional Support Office that is strategically located to help with the demand for die casting components in the Asian market. Our sales team is available to help with any of your small precision component needs.&nbsp;</p>\n<p><a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="http://www.dynacast.jp" target="_blank">www.dynacast.jp</a></p>   35.649991  139.7307153                            <p>Dynacast&nbsp;Tokyo is a sales office that is strategically located to help with the demand for die casting components in the Asian market. Our sales team is available to help with any of your small precision component needs.&nbsp;</p>                      /en/discover-dynacast/locations/dynacast-tokyo       False
4  a4535e88-d1c3-4489-b351-cb75c4658f61                         Dynacast Dongguan                        No. 88 Qiufu Road District\r\nFumin Industrial Park 2\r\nDalang, Dongguan, Guangdong 523778  86.769.8222.0638 (8801)      Asia      China         https://www.google.com/maps?daddr=No.+88+Qiufu+Road+District%2BDalang%2C+Dongguan%2BGuangdong%2BChina             <p>Dynacast Dongguan is a 14,000 square meter facility that is located in the heart of the Guangdong Province. The facility delivers high quality parts to the leading manufacturing hub in Southern China and focuses on zinc, aluminum, and magnesium die casting. Below are additional details about what is offered at the Dongguan location:</p>\n<ul>\n<li>28 zinc die casting machines ranging from 2 to 250 tons</li>\n<li>20 aluminum die casting machines ranging from 125 to 350 tons</li>\n<li>4 standard magnesium die casting machines ranging from 60 to 350 tons</li>\n<li>4 aluminum &amp; magnesium die cast machines ranging from 60 to 350 tons&nbsp;</li>\n<li>2 standard plastic injection machines up to 100 tons</li>\n<li>Precision tool building with in-house capabilities</li>\n<li>Wide range of secondary operations including CNC machining, tapping, reaming, and drilling available in house and through certified partners</li>\n<li>Design, prototyping, and modeling services</li>\n<li>Wide range of finishing surfaces available including E-coating, electroless nickel plating, bright chrome, black chrome, spray painting, black anodising, micro-arc oxidation, copper nickle chrome, powder coating and passivation</li>\n</ul>\n<p><a href="http://www.dynacast.cn" target="_blank">www.dynacast.cn</a></p>\n<p />  22.9455755  113.9313944  <p>Dynacast Dongguan is a 14,000 square meter facility that is located in the heart of the Guangdong Province. The facility delivers high quality parts to the leading manufacturing hub in Southern China and focuses on zinc, aluminum, and magnesium die casting.</p>                   /en/discover-dynacast/locations/dynacast-dongguan       False
```